# Почему не ставится фон на всю страницу (HTML + CSS)

Tags: html, css

У меня есть изображение(фон на всю страницу) называется start.jpg так вот я написал код в style.css но она не работает можете посмотреть, что с ним не так

Мой Index.JSP

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

        <style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%></style>



        <title>Home Page</title>




    </head>


    <body>



        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">KazNIC</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Наш университет</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Электронный журнал</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Студенты</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Фотогалерея</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Карьера</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Поиск</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

</div>


<div class="container">

</div>


        <div class="bg">
            <div class ="pokaz">





                <form action="allStudents" method="post">


                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Показать всех студентов">

                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
    body { 
    background-image: url(WEB-INF/images/start.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.bg{
    background-color: black;
}
.it{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}


.pokaz{

   margin: 0;

    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 


}

.add{
   width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Расположение файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: html,body{height:100%;background: red;}

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте распределить свойства по полочкам и добавить размер как-то так

```css
    background-image: url(WEB-INF/images/start.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает((

Comment: Попробуйте вставить картинку в body, эффект будет тем же, задний фон на всю страницу

Comment: Поменял все так же нету даже картинки посмотрите я вопрос правил

Comment: Обычно чтобы подняться на каталог выше используют две точки, возможно проблема в этом: вместо _WEB-INF/images/start.jpg_ попробуйте написать это _../images/start.jpg_

Comment: Блин что то не помогает можете посмотреть код может что-то не так делаю

Comment: Дайте ссылку на ваш сайт

Comment: она написана на спринге проект на java